# Regex to not match against 2 different strings

Tags: php, regex

Ok, this regex seems to not match **action=admin** within the URL that I am testing it with.  But I also need to exclude **action=dream** as well.  How can I add this to the following regex...

```
'~\b((?!\?action=admin)[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=\~_|!:,.;\[\]]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=\~_|\[\]]?)([^-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=\~_|])~'
```

Have tried the following...

```
'~\b((?!\?action=(admin|dream))[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=\~_|!:,.;\[\]]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=\~_|\[\]]?)([^-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=\~_|])~'
```

But this is giving bad results...

Comment: What are the bad results?

Comment: Well, the problem is that this changes all URLs on the page within a `preg_match_all`, so the bad results... display issues.

Comment: So the problem is with your inner match if `(admin|dream)`?

Comment: exactly!  the first regex works fine with `admin` only, but I also need to capture `?action=dream` How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to have `admin|dream` without actually capturing the value (which is what your second example does).  For this, you want to use `(?: )`, like this:

```
(?!\?action=(?:admin|dream))
```

Comment: Verified with [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/).